# Lagrange multipliers and the extrema of $f(x,y) = -x^2-y^2+x+y$

Tags: calculus, optimization, maxima-minima

Let $f(x,y) = -x^2-y^2+x+y$. Find the extrema of $f$ on unit disk. I have found these.

But I was asked an extra question: at the Lagrange point $({1\over\sqrt2}, {1\over\sqrt2})$, show that the restriction of $f$ to unit circle $f$ has a local maximum at this point but not a maximum on the whole disk? Any help or hints?

Answer (score 5):

Your function is 
$$
f(x,y)=-x^2-y^2+x+y
$$
and you would like to maximize this function subject to the points being on the unit disk, i.e.
$$
x^2+y^2\leq 1.
$$
You would need to apply the Kuhn-Tucker optimization, which is a bit different than the lagrange method because you now have an inequality constraint rather than an equality constraint. You would like to take FOCs of the Lagrangean along with the additional complementary slackness condition, i.e.
$$
\mathcal{L}(x,y,\lambda)=f(x,y)+\lambda(1-x^2-y^2)=-x^2-y^2+x+y-\lambda(x^2+y^2-1)
$$
with the optimality conditions being 
$$
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial x}=2(-\lambda-1)x+1=0
$$

$$
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial y}=2(-\lambda-1)y+1=0
$$
and the complementary slackness condition
$$
\lambda(1-x^2-y^2)=0
$$

From the first conditions, we have $x=y$, call it $a$. Then, if  $(1-x^2-y^2)>0$, we would need to have $\lambda=0$, implying that $x=y=1/2$, giving us a critical point.

If $\lambda>0$, then we would need to have $1-x^2-y^2=0$, which would mean that $x=y=1/ \sqrt{2}$

Notice that, the first critical point would give a function value
$$
f(1/2,1/2)=-1/4-1/4+1/2+1/2=1/2
$$

The second critical point on the other hand would give
$$
f(1/\sqrt{2},1/\sqrt{2})=-1/2-1/2+1/\sqrt{2}+1/\sqrt{2}=\sqrt{2}-1
$$
Notice that $f(1/2,1/2)>f(1/\sqrt{2},1/\sqrt{2})$, and as a result, $f$ is maximized at $(1/2,1/2)$ on the unit disk. The second point is the one where $f$ is maximized on the unit circle and clearly it is not the maximizer on the unit disk.

Comment: Can you please ellaborate more that why f does not attain local maximum at the point on disk but it does on circle ?

Comment: On the circle, the complementary slackness condition disappears in a way that $(1-x^2-y^2)=0$ has to hold. On a disk, we have more room to work with in terms of the condition. Put another way, the disc includes the circle, and if something is a maximizer on the disc, then it is necessarily true that it is higher (weakly higher) than anything on the circle. However, if we restrict our attention to the circle, there might be points on the disc that could have given a higher value that we ignored. The point is, the maximizer of a function does not need to appear on the boundary of the set.